# How to make Windows XP sleep after I press Win+S?

Tags: windows-xp, sleep

Nothing happens for shortcut key <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to make Windows XP sleep. Is there a light-weight tool for exactly this job?

Answer (score 4):

Lightweight solution: Hit the windows key (opens start menu), hit U (selects shutdown menu), and then hit S (selects standby mode,) and then hit enter (initiates standby).

Or, if you simply must have it bound to a single key, you could get [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and then bind that combination to a single key. It's a small program but i wouldn't describe it as "lightweight." I also have never used it, just heard good things about it.

There's also a thread on [pcguide.com](http://www.pcguide.com/vb/showthread.php?t=46222) which describes creating a suspend shortcut. And you can set hotkeys for shortcuts natively in XP. But again, I've never tried this solution.

Comment: the pcguide.com guide would work nicely, no need to download programs for this. +1 for that solution (and it does work)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) to create a shortcut on your desktop (`NirCmd.exe Standby`) you can right click on it, choose properties, and there should be a spot there somewhere for a hotkey. This hotkey doesn't work too well for me though, so instead I used [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and put this into the `AutoHotKey.ahk`:

```
#s::nircmd.exe Standby
```

This implies, of course, that you copied nircmd.exe to `C:\Windows\System32`.
Then set the file to run at Startup by copying it to the Startup folder in the All Programs menu of the Start Menu.